# recaptcha integration with separate pages

Tags: php, google-api, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to add captcha to my website and am trying to get the thank you to open in a different page instead of using php within the same file, how do i go about doing this?

I understand it is the section of php surrounding the form however I don't know how to change it to send to a separate thank you page.

**EDIT - If i add an action page the captcha breaks but the form submits and when I take the action out the captcha works but does not submit**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

// grab recaptcha library
require_once "recaptchalib.php";

  // your secret key
$secret = "MY SECRET KEY";

// empty response
$response = null;

// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// if submitted check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}
?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<!--js-->
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<title>MATA captcha test</title>

</head>

<body>


<?php
  if ($response != null && $response->success) {
    echo "Hi " . $_POST["name"] . " (" . $_POST["email"] . "), thanks for submitting the form!";
  } else {
?>
    <form action="" method="post">

      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input name="name" required><br />

      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" required><br />

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY KEY"></div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

<?php } ?>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

`<form action="insert_your_site_here.php" method="post">`

instead of

`<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: when i add the action the captcha doesn't work anymore, the captcha only seems to work when it doesn't post to another page?

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by not working?

Does the other page exist? Do you use the `POST` on the other page? Does the captcha fail to verify?

Comment: when the action page is added the page just moves onward without needing to validate with the captcha but when the action page is removed the captcha is needed to send the form, however the form doesnt actually submit..does this make any more sense?

Comment: On the other page, are you doing all the checks with the `POST` and the `$response` before submitting the form?

Comment: i think its something to do with <?php
  if ($response != null && $response->success) {
    echo "Hi " . $_POST["name"] . " (" . $_POST["email"] . "), thanks for submitting the form!";
  } else {
?> this bit code

Comment: So, you're saying the captcha failed to verify? Are both of those pages included in the key settings?